# Fetch specific images from a directory with php

Tags: php

```
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

With the above code I can fetch all images in a folder.But, I am not able to fetch particular images from a folder.

For example:
I have images in a folder as:

```
1. low_0.jpg
2. low_1.jpg
3. low_2.jpg
4. med_0.jpg
5  med_1.jpg
6. med_2.jpg
```

From these images how to grab only the images that starts with `med`?
 Thanks for your time

Comment: @Rizier123 how to use preg_grep() here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `glob()` command from:

```
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
```

To:

```
$images = glob($dirname."med_*.jpg");
```

The `*` is a wildcard; it'll fill in the gap (in this case, numbers).

---

Full code:

```
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."med_*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks bt It doesnt work. It shows all images in the folder

Comment: @SushangNirola this should work, there's nothing wrong with it. The problem is on your side.

Comment: Try with this                                                                                        `$images  = glob($dirname."[med_]*.jpg");`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ya, it happened to be a problem at my side. It is working now.

Comment: @SushangNirola Great, glad to hear it. *Cheers*